# Adding UIView without addSubview Method

Tags: ios, uiview, uialertview

I have been using UIAlertViews in my application and I noticed that after declaring them they show up on the screen just by calling:

```
[alert release];
[alert show];
```

How can the UIAlertView show up on the screen without calling the addSubview method? Also how could I make my UIView show up with just a "show" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think an alert view is displayed without `addSubview:` being called?

It turns out that the implementation of the `show` method is that it creates a 2nd window in your app and then it creates and adds the alert view to that window, using `addSubview:`. It's just an internal implementation detail that you don't see.

You can write your own `show` method if you want. But its implementation will need to create a view and call `addSubview:` at some point.

Comment: Wow! Learn something new everyday! Thanks!

Comment: +1 quite thought provoking. On that line, modal views aren't very different from alert. But they are made part of navigation hierarchy where they become children of navcontroller. What is Apple's logic behind having different consideration for modal view vs alert view?

Comment: @NiravBhatt Modally presented view controllers are more likely to stay visible for a long(er) period while UIAlertViews were (deprecated in iOS8) designed to be discarded immediately.